# Html5 video – different seek bar behaviour depending on play / pause

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, seekbar

Trying to achieve the following functionality of a custom Html5 video player:

If the video is playing:
the video should pause during seeking and continue playing afterwards

If the video is paused:
the video should stay paused during seeking and stay paused afterwards

Here’s a fiddle that shows that the seek bar (or slider thumb) is flickering during seeking if you drag a little longer. The video doesn’t pause during seeking if the video is playing. Might be a problem with my if/else function, but I really don’t know where my error is. Glad if somebody can help :)

https://jsfiddle.net/ggxj67w9/

I want to use jquery or javascript and I don’t want to use a library like jplayer or video.js

Here’s my seekbar code:

```
seekBar.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var time = video.duration * (seekBar.value / 100);
  video.currentTime = time;
});

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
  var value = (100 / video.duration) * video.currentTime;
  seekBar.value = value;
});

function vidSeek() {
 if (video.paused) {
    seekBar.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
      video.pause();
    });
    seekBar.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
      video.pause();
    });
 } else {
    seekBar.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
      video.pause();
    });
    seekBar.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
      video.play();
    });
 }
}
```